# Grunt to export specific files from svn

Tags: svn, gruntjs, npm

I'm looking for a npm grunt module that will help me export specific files **(not directories)** from svn repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not export files. You can only `svn cat FILE > filename`